# .Net Runtime 2.0 Error - EventId 5000

Tags: .net

I have a recurring problem with a site that keeps giving me .Net Runtime 2.0 Errors in the Application Event Log, with Event ID 5000.  The event details are:

EventType clr20r3, P1 w3wp.exe, P2 6.0.3790.3959, P3 45d691cc, P4 app_web_n93dosww, P5 0.0.0.0, P6 4b322f31, P7 37, P8 195, P9 pageerrorexception, P10 NIL.

Looking on the web for this type of error, I found this article [Unhandled exceptions cause ASP.NET-based applications to unexpectedly quit in the .NET Framework 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=911816)

to give me more details of the exception, but for these errors, nothing extra is logged (the module in that article is working - if I add in the code they suggest to reproduce the error, the extra detail is logged).

My question is really, if it is an unhandled exception that is causing these crashes, what situations could be causing it be unhandled?  The exception type in the message, pageerrorexception, is a custom exception that is thrown in a few different places on a few different pages, so it should be easy enough to track down.  But I can't see any situation where it would be unhandled and cause a crash.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add an application OnError event and save all errors to log, including stack trace. Then analyze the log to find all unhanded pageerrorexception.